# Xpath 2 attributes php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am doing some sort of filter for profile pages dont say sql because I dont have access, the example xml below:

```
<member id="1" name="name" username=""/>
```

and I want php to get all 3 values.
Im using simplexml

Comment: What library are you using? DOMDocument, simple_xml?

Comment: SimpleXML is the library check question :-)

Answer (score 0):

As your question is quite ambiguous, I mindread you have the `id` and want to get `name` and `username`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$member = $xml->xpath("//member[@id = '1']")[0];
echo "name: " . $member['name'] . ", username: " . $member['username'] . PHP_EOL;
```

This requires `PHP >= 5.4`, for the `[0]` at the end of `line 2`. For older versions of PHP, do:

```
$member = $xml->xpath("//member[@id = '1']");
$member = $member[0];
```

This is because `xpath`will return an array of `SimpleXml Elements`, and we need the first one only.

see it working: https://eval.in/116515